# I can't get text selected QT GUI

Tags: qt, python-2.x, linux-mint

I m trying to create a code that it can get a selected text, but I can't get text from QT windows. I'm using linux mint 19.3 and my little code that I m using to test. Can some one help me ?

```
import os

var = os.popen('xsel').read()
print var
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Perhaps the Qt application runs under wayland, not X (or vice-versa). See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1758873